# net use command to show _all_ connections

Tags: windows, network-share, net

When I type `net use` as `Admin` on my Windows 7 Machine, I see no shared drives mounted.
However, there are drives connected by users. When I start the windows `cmd` shell with one of these users, I see these drives listed with `net use`.

How do you list the drives mounted by all users on Windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The net use command refers to the currently logged in user(*). Nothing more, nothing less.

It is possible to authenticate as another user as part of a net use command of course, but that's about as multi-user as it gets.

The NET command is an old [lan manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAN_Manager) command, essentially, and commands like net use are designed to allow a user to manage their connections, not a sysadmin to manage a machine.

Comment: IThis explains why it doesn't work but doesn't address the OP question of how he or she can list the drives mounted by all the users.

Comment: `How do you list the drives mounted by all users on Windows 7?` -- technically it is still just the `net use` command, you just run it twice.  Once for the normal user token and once for the admin token.

Answer (score 3):

This really probably belongs on SuperUser, but:

You could write a script that searches through the HKEY_USERS hive in the registry. In particular, the `HKEY_USERS\<UserSID>\Network` has keys for each drive mapped.

Comment: is the net command that limited?

Comment: @Oz123 Yes, it is. It's from the ol' DOS days...